# Generate a grid in Swift using Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have an app idea so mocked it up in C# because that's my most fluent language. I now want to port this over to Swift if possible, how hard will it be to generate a grid of 6x6 blocks, each block needs to be separate from each other as I need to change they're properties and detect touches on them. [This is the grid I've currently got running on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dqbU.png).
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to approach this problem, so you need to provide more details. You could do it with a single custom UIView, drawing the current representation of your model in the drawRect method and it would also be able to handle all of the touch events since you can just calculate where the user did the touch in the same way that you calculated drawing the grid and coloring the squares.

But if you want to use SpriteKit, then this tutorial will show you all the details of doing a 2D array, using sprites, tiles, etc.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/75270/make-game-like-candy-crush-with-swift-tutorial-part-1